# What makes us look into camera lens when we're being filmed?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, communication, eye-movement

I haven't met a person who wouldn't at least glance at a camera's lens from time to time when they're aware it's capturing an image or a video of them.

Usually creatures transmit a lot of information through their eyes and face, so it's natural for us to look at someone's eyes, but when we know cameras don't work like that, why do we still keep looking at them?

Comment: I would say it is just that we feel being watched by it, and when something watches us, we feel more confortable looking it in the eyes (or lens). I know there is some research on this topic done with robots (which also only look through cameras), I just can't remember more details. Of course, a robot is more than just plain camera, but I think it is the same matter. We see faces in everything and we see observers in cameras, because it is important for us to not miss them. Who knows what they are up to :)

Comment: For what it's worth I often take photographs of animals, specifically birds. I have noticed the same behavior. They seem to understand that the camera lens is like a giant eye and will consistently look at it/ keep watching it. It's likely that it's foreign to them and they feel threatened by it but they act differently towards a lens than any other object I have seen them react to...

Comment: From Yotsuba& I've learned that birds will treat almost every [eye-looking object](https://www.google.ru/search?q=scareeye&tbm=isch) as a whole, potentially dangerous, creature. Not sure why it works with people, who do understand that it's just a piece of technology. Maybe some threatening feeling of a bad angle shot has its effect?

Comment: Ive read about autistic girl being model with notice the good thing were she didn't automatically stare into lens, so it could be the same mechanism that makes us looking in people's eyes.

Comment: @ChrisStronks This is okay.  It's something that is an objective, testable phenomenon and may have answers in the literature.  In general, just because a question asserts that something might be true doesn't make it a matter of opinion.

Comment: Nonetheless, the poster should do at least a minimum of research before expressing an opinion and/or asking a question that is likely to invite opinion, so as to narrow down the type of research they are after.